# Sender address rejected

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm trying to use PHPMAILER, but I keep getting:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 smart6.bol.com.br ESMTP
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-smart6.bol.com.br 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 13312000 250-VRFY 250-ETRN 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN 250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN 250 8BITMIME
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Ok
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:553 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user X
SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 553 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user deltrem1984@bol.com.br
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: deltrem1984@bol.com.br
```

What should I do?

Comment: What email address do you have in the FROM: field of your test mail?

Comment: Does your mail server use postfix?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Often for anti-spam purposes, "$mail->From" is required to be the same address as you use for login to your SMTP server.

If that is your case, you can use the "$mail->AddReplyTo" field for the senders address instead. Only a suggestion.

If it is not the solution, some extra debugging information can be enabled by setting

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also be careful about email address aliases, because your SMTP server may be rejecting your mails for that reason (it depends on server configuration).